# Creating JSON object from Python's dictionary

Tags: python, json

The following code was used to create JSON.
But I have \ in JSON.

```
"[{\"1_245_183_424_225_251_188_416_219_SJA4549J.jpeg\": {\"fileref\": \"\", \"size\": 0, \"filename\": \"1_245_183_424_225_251_188_416_219_SJA4549J.jpeg\", \"file_attributes\": {}, \"regions\": {\"plate\": {\"shape_attributes\": {\"name\": \"polygon\", \"all_points_x\": [], \"all_points_y\": []}, \"region_attributes\": {\"width\": 720, \"height\": 720, \"depth\": 3}}}}}, {\"1_245_183_424_225_251_188_416_219_SJA4549J.jpeg\": {\"fileref\": \"\", \"size\": 0, \"filename\": \"1_245_183_424_225_251_188_416_219_SJA4549J.jpeg\", \"file_attributes\": {}, \"regions\": {\"textline\": {\"shape_attributes\": {\"name\": \"polygon\", \"all_points_x\": [], \"all_points_y\": []}, \"region_attributes\": {\"width\": 720, \"height\": 720, \"depth\": 3}}}}}, {\"IMG_20200214_081450.jpeg\": {\"fileref\": \"\", \"size\": 0, \"filename\": \"IMG_20200214_081450.jpeg\", \"file_attributes\": {}, \"regions\": {\"plate\": {\"shape_attributes\": {\"name\": \"polygon\", \"all_points_x\": [], \"all_points_y\": []}, \"region_attributes\": {\"width\": 720, \"height\": 720, \"depth\": 3}}}}}, {\"IMG_20200214_081450.jpeg\": {\"fileref\": \"\", \"size\": 0, \"filename\": \"IMG_20200214_081450.jpeg\", \"file_attributes\": {}, \"regions\": {\"plate\": {\"shape_attributes\": {\"name\": \"polygon\", \"all_points_x\": [], \"all_points_y\": []}, \"region_attributes\": {\"width\": 720, \"height\": 720, \"depth\": 3}}}}}, {\"IMG_20200214_081450.jpeg\": {\"fileref\": \"\", \"size\": 0, \"filename\": \"IMG_20200214_081450.jpeg\", \"file_attributes\": {}, \"regions\": {\"textline\": {\"shape_attributes\": {\"name\": \"polygon\", \"all_points_x\": [], \"all_points_y\": []}, \"region_attributes\": {\"width\": 720, \"height\": 720, \"depth\": 3}}}}}, {\"IMG_20200214_081450.jpeg\": {\"fileref\": \"\", \"size\": 0, \"filename\": \"IMG_20200214_081450.jpeg\", \"file_attributes\": {}, \"regions\": {\"textline\": {\"shape_attributes\": {\"name\": \"polygon\", \"all_points_x\": [], \"all_points_y\": []}, \"region_attributes\": {\"width\": 720, \"height\": 720, \"depth\": 3}}}}}]"
```

Then I also have "[ at the beginning and ]" at end of file in printing to JSON file.
Why I have those at the beginning and end of JSON file and how to remove?

The code is as follow.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pickle
from os import listdir, getcwd
from os.path import join
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
import random
import json
xmlspath="/home/itc/Data/NumberPlate/PlateDetection/annotations/xmls/"


xmlFiles = [f for f in listdir(xmlspath) if f.endswith("." + "xml")];
num_objs = 0
iou = 0.0
num_hits = 0
train = []
val = []
for idx,xmlFile in enumerate(xmlFiles):
   if(idx > 10):
      break
   tree = ET.parse(xmlspath+xmlFile)
   root = tree.getroot()
   filename = xmlFile.split(".")[0]+".jpeg"
   size = root.find("size")
   width = int(size.find("width").text)
   height = int(size.find("height").text)
   depth = int(size.find("depth").text)
   for obj in root.iter("object"):
      newitem={
  "name":{"fileref":"","size":0,"filename":"","file_attributes":{},"regions":{"attribute":{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[],"all_points_y":[]},"region_attributes":{"width":0,"height":0,"depth":3}}}}  
}
      newitem[filename]=newitem.pop("name")
      newitem[filename]["filename"]=filename
      bndbox = obj.find("bndbox")
      category = obj.find("name")
      xmin=int(bndbox.find("xmin").text)
      ymin=int(bndbox.find("ymin").text)
      xmax=int(bndbox.find("xmax").text)
      ymax=int(bndbox.find("ymax").text)
      if(obj.find("name").text == "plate"):
         newitem[filename]["regions"]["plate"] = newitem[filename]["regions"].pop("attribute")
         newitem[filename]["regions"]["plate"]["region_attributes"]["width"]=width
         newitem[filename]["regions"]["plate"]["region_attributes"]["height"]=height  
      elif(obj.find("name").text == "textline"):
         newitem[filename]["regions"]["textline"] = newitem[filename]["regions"].pop("attribute")
         newitem[filename]["regions"]["textline"]["region_attributes"]["width"]=width
         newitem[filename]["regions"]["textline"]["region_attributes"]["height"]=height                  
      if(idx%8 == 0):
         val.append(newitem)
      else:
         train.append(newitem)
      print(idx)
      

jsontrain = json.dumps(train)
jsonval = json.dumps(val)
with open("numplate/train/train.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(jsontrain, outfile)
with open("numplate/val/val.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(jsonval, outfile)
```

Comment: You're JSON-encoding your JSON string. Don't both `dump` *and* `dumps` the value.

Comment: Cant you mininize a little? 

It seems like you are serializing twice...

Comment: And you have a `[]` because you're creating and dumping a list.

Comment: @deceze thanks I just need dump to JSON file.

Comment: @deceze how to remove []

Comment: Don't create a list. I don't know what else you'd want, since you explicitly declare those values as `[]` and `append` to it in a loop…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you have  **"[ at the beginning and ]" at end of file"** is that because your objects (val an train) are lists (not dictionaries)

First you have to convert them:

```
train = {"items" : train}
val =  = {"items" : val}
```

Then, for your encoding issue you can force the `json.dump()` function to not add the "" symbol by setting the `ensure_ascii` to `False`:

```
with open("numplate/train/train.json", 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    json.dump(train, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: "The "\" symbol" has nothing to do with `ensure_ascii`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html
It is mentioned in the official doc that " If ensure_ascii is true (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the result is a str instance consisting of ASCII characters only."

Comment: Yeah, that just has nothing to do with the added backslashes nor quotes. Those are all ASCII characters, and are added for different reasons. `ensure_ascii` only impacts non-ASCII characters, e.g. it causes ”漢字" to be output as `"\u6f22\u5b57"` instead of `"漢字"`.